# PHP preg_replace special characters

Tags: php

I am wanting to replace all non letter and number characters i.e. `/&%#$` etc with an underscore `(_)` and replace all `'` (single quotes) with ""blank (so no underscore).

So "**There wouldn't be any**" (ignore the double quotes) would become "**There_wouldnt_be_any**".

I am useless at reg expressions hence the post.

Cheers

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
$newstr = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\']/', '_', "There wouldn't be any");
$newstr = str_replace("'", '', $newstr);
```

I put them on two separate lines to make the code a little more clear.

Note: If you're looking for Unicode support, see Filip's answer below. It will match all characters that register as letters in addition to `A-z`.

Comment: With this i had problems with special polish chars like ż ź ć
\p{N} \p{L} is better solution. But not working on js.

Comment: @MarcinJaworski Make sure you pass the `u` flag to ensure unicode matching. JS regex also does not use quotes, so you're left with `/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u`

Answer (score 42):

If you by writing "*non letters and numbers*" exclude more than `[A-Za-z0-9]` (ie. considering letters like `åäö` to be letters to) and want to be able to accurately handle UTF-8 strings `\p{L}` and `\p{N}` will be of aid.

1. `\p{N}` will match any "*Number*"
2. `\p{L}` will match any "*Letter Character*", which includes

   - Lower case letter
   - Modifier letter
   - Other letter
   - Title case letter
   - Upper case letter

Documentation [PHP: Unicode Character Properties](http://se.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

---

```
$data = "Thäre!wouldn't%bé#äny";

$new_data = str_replace  ("'", "", $data);
$new_data = preg_replace ('/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u', '_', $new_data);

var_dump (
  $new_data
);
```

output

```
string(23) "Thäre_wouldnt_bé_äny"
```

Comment: In my case ßällistic was replaced by ÃŸÃ¤llistic after the upload.

Comment: @erdomester has your version of PCRE (the regular expression engine) been compiled with support for UTF-8?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. The file is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM. I am using FileZilla

Comment: @erdomester seems like your problem is not related to the code-snippet provided but with the encoding of the file vs encoding of the output in your browser

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp what if I want to limit the name string to be using just one language script? For example, "송 Mary" this kind of mix should not be allowed.

Comment: @congliu could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

do this in two steps:

1. replace not letter characters with [this](http://regexr.com?2vf65) regex:

   `[\/\&%#\$]`
2. replace quotes with [this](http://regexr.com?2vf6e) regex:

   `[\"\']`

and use `preg_replace`:

```
$stringWithoutNonLetterCharacters = preg_replace("/[\/\&%#\$]/", "_", $yourString);
$stringWithQuotesReplacedWithSpaces = preg_replace("/[\"\']/", " ", $stringWithoutNonLetterCharacters);
```