# Best preg_match expression for international name

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to find a good `preg_match` expression that allow all letters (included accented letters), the space , and these symbols: `- '`

I thought this could be a good solution `'/^\p{L}+$/ui'`, but I can't find a successful way to add the symbols I need, if that is possible...

Otherwise I guess I should use something like this:

```
'#^[a-zA-Z0-9àòäöüÄÖÜ \.\]]+$#'
```

but there are so many accents that I was hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: check out the second answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483546/php-preg-replace-special-characters

Comment: `[A-zÀ-ú]` is a step forward.

Comment: Ok, something like this seems to work good `"/[^- 'A-zÀ-ú]/u" `

Comment: >I'd do: `.+` or may be `.*`. Have a look at http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the `\p{L}` and allowed symbols inside brackets:

```
$name = "B-jör n'Bòrg";
if (preg_match("/^[- '\p{L}]+$/u", $name)) {
    echo "$name is a valid name!"; // It is
}
```

You may also want to add some additional checks, e.g. to make sure that names starts and ends with a letter and not a symbol.

**Edit**

This will make sure that names starts/ends with a letter and does not contain consecutive symbols:

```
$name = "-Björ n''Bòrg-";
if (preg_match("/^\p{L}([- ']\p{L}|\p{L})*$/u", $name)) {
    echo "$name is a valid name!"; // It's not
}
```