# str_replace special apostrophe does not work

Tags: php, str-replace, apostrophe

I have a text with a weird apostrophe, that is not on my keyboard. I need to replace that in code, but it just does not happen. Code would be like this:

```
$proj_copy="(Along Sixth Avenue)’ Project Description Designed";
$proj_copy=str_replace("’","X",$proj_copy);
```

If I replace the searched character ’ with any other, it works.
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: [Can't reproduce your problem](https://3v4l.org/aFUGc)

Comment: it worked for me. Which weird apostrophe do you have ? Try finding it please

Comment: The output is exactly the same as before you used str_replace()?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the other way round and just remove all characters which are not in a charset you define. You could do this with regex.
Look here: [Replace special chars with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483546/php-preg-replace-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

try this if it worked for you....

```
str_replace("\"","&quot;",str_replace("'","''",$proj_copy))
```

may this will help

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as shown in your question, works.

BUT you have to make sure that the file encoding of your PHP source is UTF-8. If not, depending on your editor you may see the proper apostrophe character without it being actually stored on disk. If you close the file and re-open it you may see that the character is gone or garbled. It would mean that your encoding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your string is encoded in the same character set as your source code. Your code as it is should work (if the string is in the file).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$proj_copy=html_entity_decode(str_replace("#rsquo;", "'", htmlentities($proj_copy)));
```

where `#` is `&`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).