# How to replace special character ' /' in php with another special character

Tags: php

How to replace special character '/' in a string  in php.
I just want replace only this special character, not all special character

For eg,

$str= 3/26, 5/15, 5/20, 5/26-5/28;

I want to replace / with -.

I want to replace'/' with something as passing this string to form a xml is giving error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_replace special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483546/php-preg-replace-special-characters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace certain parts of my string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163746/how-to-replace-certain-parts-of-my-string)

Comment: No able to find solution

Answer (score 0):

You would use `str_replace(search, replace, subject)`

ex:

```
$str = '3/26, 5/15, 5/20, 5/26-5/28';
$str = str_replace("/", '-', $str);
```

outputs:

> 3-26, 5-15, 5-20, 5-26-5-28

Comment: I am getting output as 3/26, 5/15, 5/20, 5/26-5/28. str_replace is not working in this case.

Comment: @VAD can you show the code? because I've tested and it outputs correctly [Link Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdmk4eVpYMkE1SlU)

Answer (score 0):

`$str = '3/26, 5/15, 5/20, 5/26-5/28';` was being pulled from Php-MyAdmin which is using html entities to get user input.

So when I decoded using function below:

```
html_entity_decode(str_replace('&sol;', '/', $sValue), ENT_COMPAT | ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
```

and then used `str_replace`, I was able to get the result.