# PHP -- how to remove special character

Tags: php, special-characters

A special string ： " the famous �red door� ";
how can i  remove the special character : � , that I can get: "the famous re door"

Comment: with [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), https://3v4l.org/XrnbA

Comment: this should help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483546/php-preg-replace-special-characters

Comment: This is very likely to be an encoding error. If you start manipulating broken text, you can easily end up with corrupted data and technical debt, but fixing the problem in the source should not be hard. Is your application/database using UTF-8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP preg\_replace special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483546/php-preg-replace-special-characters)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To remove all the characters that do not fall under the above criteria, you have to add ^ after the opening angle bracket so the regular expression to be [^a-zA-Z0-9\s!?.,'"].

Example

```
<?php
$str = "Hey @there#! How ( are) you *d_oing/?";
echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s!?.,\'\"]/", "", $str);
```